# Exercise about limit point of a sequence in cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

I was given the following exercise. Let $X$ be a topological space with the cofinite topology. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$ such that for every $y$ in $X$ there are infinte indeces $m$ in $\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_m \neq y$. Show that every $x \in X$ is a limit point of the sequence.

I proceeded as follows: $x$ is a limit point if for every neighborhood $U$ of x, for every $N \in  \mathbb{N}$ there are infinite $n \ge N$ s.t. $x_n \in U$. Let $U=X-\{y_1, \ldots, y_k\}$, with $y_i\neq x$. There are infinite indeces s.t. $x_m \neq y_i$, then there are infinite indices s.t $x_m \in U$.

A friend of mine pointed out that, if the sequence is periodic, i.e. $x_{k+1}=x_1$ etc., and we take exactly $U=X-\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ there is no $m$ s.t. $x_m \in U$!

Do you think the problem lies in the text of the exercise or in my argument?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whoever posed the exercise fell into the same trap as you. As stated, the assertion does not hold. The example of your friend shows this (the sequence need nod be periodic, see below, but periodic sequences are the counterexamples most easy to explicitly define). The correct assertion that was probably aimed for is

> Let $X$ be a space endowed with the cofinite topology, and $(x_n)$ a sequence in $X$. If the set $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is infinite, then every $x \in X$ is a limit point of the sequence.

From the start of your argument, the conclusion is easy to reach with the correct hypothesis.

For the exercise as stated, your argument doesn't work because while the statement guarantees that for each $i$ there are infinitely many $m$ with $x_m \neq y_i$, nothing prevents all those $x_m$ to equal $y_j$ for some $j \neq i$, as illustrated by a periodic but not constant sequence.